# setting mysql user-defined variable with query-builder

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, variables

I have an issue with setting mysql user-defined variables with codeigniter. How am I able to use SET with CI query builder?

```
SET @weekVideoCount := (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM videos v );

SELECT @weekVideoCount;
```

When I execute this Query on Sqlyog the result will be successfully shown but if I call this Query in the model like this

```
function getWeeklyUserData(){
        $query= $this->db->query("SET @weekVideoCount := (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM videos v);
                                SELECT @weekVideoCount;
                                ");
        return $query->result();
    }
```

the error has generated

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try separate the query

```
 $this->db->query("SET @weekVideoCount := (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM videos v)");
 $query= $this->db->query("SELECT @weekVideoCount");
```

Comment: FYI this works too

```SELECT @rn:=@rn+1 AS rank FROM (SELECT (SELECT @rn:=0) )```

Answer (score 2):

you should know $this->db->query() execute only one sql statement just like mysql_query.